# Adding overflow-y to block element causes width to decrease.

Tags: css, overflow, fixed-width, liquid-layout

This is what I have, I have left div, and a right div.  The left div is a fixed width, and floated left.  The right Div is a "display: block" to make it full width, and has a margin on the left to compensate for the left div.  Both of the boxes have a fixed height, and need to be scrollable (the contents inside).  I add an overflow-y to the Left div successfully.  However when I add overflow-y: auto to the right div, the div no longer spans the whole div.

Before adding Overflow:
http://jsbin.com/asecuy/

After adding Overflow:
http://jsbin.com/asecuy/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset

```
.eventdetails {
    margin-left: 252px;
}
```

This margin is causing the bug. I'm guessing it just doesn't play nice together with overflow-y and the float next to it (should work though I think).

Here it is working:

http://jsbin.com/asecuy/3/#html

Comment: Wow, Thanks, completely overlooked that.