# overflow-y: auto|scroll causes horizontal shift

Tags: css, overflow, centering

I'm having a problem similar to [Adding overflow-y to block element causes width to decrease.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504896/adding-overflow-y-to-block-element-causes-width-to-decrease), but I want my right div to be centered horizontally. So I have "margin: auto;" on the right div.

This worked fine until I added "overflow-y: auto" (or scroll) to the right div. Before this, the margins were measured from the entire page width. After adding it, it measures from the right edge of the left div, so instead of being centered on the page, it's centered on the remaining portion of the page.

Simple demo of the problem at:

http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/demo-overflow.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add position:absolute; to the sidebar to achieve the same effect with the second example.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason why but as you stated the overflow-y is causing the right div to center on the remaining portion of the page. By adding position:absolute to the left div (which causes it to ignore float: left; by the way) you remove it from the normal flow of the document which causes the right div to center in the page as if the left div isn't there.

Answer (score 4):

When you add an `overflow` property on your `div`, you define a new formating context. As stated in the [MDN documentation on this subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context), `float` influence is limited to a specific formatting context. Formatting contexts are defined by specific rules listed in the aforementioned doc.

`position: absolute` is a solution, but you must understand that absolutely positionned elements are positioned relatively to their last positionned ancestor (i.e. one with a `position` attribute with a value different of `static` (the default one)). Also [look at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) to fully grasp this concept.

You can read [this article on SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/floatclear) that deeply explains floated elements. You should more specifically be interested in the section *Floating Versus Absolute Positioning for Multi-column Layouts*.